# How to delete multiple files using rm command?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

Is there a command that lets me delete `package.json` file and `node_modules` directory in a single command rather than `rm- rf <file/directory name>` two times in this scenario?

If there is, is it different for multiple directories and different for multiple files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can; you just need to separate the target objects with a space.

For example:

```
rm -rf folder file.txt
```

(Where `-r` is 'recursive', and `-f` is 'force')

Note: option `-rf` is being used to delete the folder. If you tried the above without that option, only the file would be deleted, and you'd get something like:

> rm: cannot remove 'folder': Is a directory

As for different directories:

```
rm file.txt folder/file2.txt
```